# Multiple markers - google maps

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to put multiple markers on my google maps. Here is my code

```
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(43.9433844,16.5050116);
var myCenter2=new google.maps.LatLng(43.9507941,16.5313844);
var myCenter1=new google.maps.LatLng(43.9438657,16.4915124);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
center:myCenter,
zoom:14,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
position:myCenter2,
position:myCenter1,
});

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and in html

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%; height:450px;"></div>
```

This not working. It's showing only one marker. 
If I try with this tutorial http://chrisltd.com/blog/2013/08/google-map-random-color-pins/ , the maps don't show. 
Also, I tried with this https://gist.github.com/parth1020/4481893, and again, maps are not showing. It only works with first code, but shows only one marker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're only inserting 1 marker, and overwriting the earlier position. You should include them all with seperate markers:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter1,
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter2,
});
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter3,
});

marker1.setMap(map)
marker2.setMap(map)
marker3.setMap(map)
```

Comment: thanx, that was what i need.